# Explanation for MSE formula for vector comparison with "Euclidean distance"?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, euclidean

I study the loss functions for regression tasks with artificial neural networks. In case of evaluating loss with Mean Squared Error for multidimensional outputs I read the following usual formula which is straightforward for me (N is the number of samples, M is the output dimensionality):

[image]

However, I also confronted with a slightly different format:

[image]

The accompanying explanation says:

"*You’ll recognize the inner sigma in the preceding equation as the square of the Euclidean distance. In fact, the MSE is sometimes referred to by these terms. Note that N and M are constants. So, consider these as simple scaling factors that you can account for in other ways (like by scaling the learning rate). In a lot of use cases M is dropped and a division by two is added for mathematical convenience (which will become clearer in the context of its gradient in backpropagation).*"

I cannot follow this explanation (and neither the second formula).

- What is the connection between the formula and the Euclidean
  distance?
- How does the fact that "N and M are constants" explain
  anything?
- How scaling factors come into the picture?
- What is the "mathematical convenience" here and how does it become clearer in backpropagation? (I'm more or less familiar with backprop).

Comment: Where did you find those definitions?

Answer (score 3):

> What is the connection between the formula and the Euclidean distance?

Consider the formula of the Euclidean Distance between $\hat{y}$ and $ y $ when they have same dimensionality:

$ D = \sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^n (\hat{y}_{i} - y_{i})^2 } $

so the square is:

$ D^2 = {\sum_{i=0}^n (\hat{y}_{i} - y_{i})^2 } $

that is very close to you formula except for the factors $N$ and $M$.

> How does the fact that "N and M are constants" explain anything?
>   How scaling factors come into the picture?

Basically, the fact that $ N $ and $ M $ are costants means that they you can see them as scaling factors. Indeed you will divide your amount always for the same quantity.

> What is the "mathematical convenience" here and how does it become
>   clearer in backpropagation? (I'm more or less familiar with backprop).

It's just for a matter of convenience, because in the backprogation you need to compute the derivative of your squared term. So if your loss function (bias omitted for simplicity) is:

$ L = \frac{1}{2N} \sum_{i=0}^n (\hat{y}_{ij} - y_{ij})^2 $

when apply the power rule on it for getting the derivative wrt the weights, you obtain:

$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial W}  = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=0}^n (\hat{y}_{ij} -y_{ij}) $

So the constant $ 2 $ has disappear from the equation.